# How to pass a Bash command to `entr`, quoting to guard against filenames with spaces?

Tags: bash, quoting, parameter-expansion

### My Goal

I'm writing a small Bash script, which uses [`entr`](https://eradman.com/entrproject/), which is a utility to re-run arbitrary commands when it detects file-system events. My immediate goal is to pass `entr` a command which converts a given markdown file to HTML. `entr` will run this command every time the markdown file changes. A simplified but working script looks like:

```bash
# script 1
in="$1"
out="${in%.md}.html"
echo "$in" | entr pandoc "${in}" -o "${out}"
```

This works fine. The filename to be watched is supplied to `entr` on stdin. On detecting changes in that file, `entr` runs the command specified by its args. In this example that is `pandoc`, and all the args after it, to convert the markdown file to an HTML file.

For future reference, `set -x` shows that `entr` was invoked as we'd expect. (Throughout, lines starting with `+` show the output from `set -x`):

```
+ entr pandoc 'READ ME.md' -o 'READ ME.html'
```

### The problem

I want to look-up the command given to `entr` depending on the file-type of the
given input file. So the file-conversion command ends up in a variable, and I want to use that variable as the command-line args to `entr`. But I can't get the quoting right.
Again, simplified:

```bash
# script 2
in="$1"
out="${in%.md}.html"
cmd="pandoc \"${in}\" -o \"${out}\""
echo "$in" | entr "$cmd"
```

(shellcheck.net detects no issues on the above)

This fails. Because `"$cmd"` in the final line is in quotes, the entirety of `$cmd`
is treated as a single arg to `entr`:

```
+ entr 'pandoc "READ ME.md" -o "READ ME.html"'
```

`entr` tries to interpret the whole thing as the name of an executable, which
it cannot find:

```
entr: exec pandoc "READ ME.md" -o "READ ME.html": No such file or directory
```

So how should I modify script 2, to use the content of `$cmd` as the args to
`entr`?

### What have I tried?

1. Check that `$cmd` is being formed as I expect? If I `echo "$cmd"` right after
   it is defined in script 2, it looks exactly how I'd hope:

   ```bash
   pandoc "READ ME.md" -o "READ ME.html"
   ```

   I tried messing around with alternate ways of constructing `cmd`, such as:

   ```bash
   cmd='pandoc "'"${in}"'" -o "'"${out}"'"'
   ```

   but variations like this produce identical values of `$cmd`, and identical
   behavior as script2.
2. Try *not* quoting the use of `$cmd`?

   Since the final line of script 2 erroneously treats the whole of `"$cmd"`
   as a single arg, and we want it to split up the words into seprate args
   instead, maybe removing the quotes and using a bare `$cmd` is a step in the
   right direction?

   ```bash
   echo "$in" | entr $cmd
   ```

   Predictably enough though, this splits `$cmd` up on *every* space, even the
   ones inside our double-quotes:

   ```
   + entr pandoc '"READ' 'ME.md"' -o '"READ' 'ME.html"'
   ```

   This makes Pandoc try, and fail, to open a file called `"READ`:

   ```
   pandoc: "READ: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
   ```
3. Try constructing `$cmd` using `printf`?

   I notice `printf -v` can store output in a variable. How about using that
   instead of assiging to `cmd`?

   ```bash
   printf -v cmd 'pandoc "%s" -o "%s"' "$in" "$out"
   ```

   Predictably enough, this produces the same results as script2. I tried some
   speculative variations, such as `%q` in the format string, or using `$in`
   and `$out` directly in the format string, but didn't stumble on anything
   that seemed to help.
4. Try using the `${var@Q}` form of parameter expansion.

   ```bash
   echo "$in" | entr ${cmd@Q}
   ```

   Tried with and without double quotes around the use of `${cmd@q}`. No joy,
   I guess I'm misunderstanding what `@Q` is for.

   ```
   + entr ''\''pandoc' '"READ' 'ME.md"' -o '"READ' 'ME.html"'\'''
   entr: exec 'pandoc: No such file or directory
   ```

### Details

I'm using Bash v5.1.16, in Pop!_OS 22.04, derived from Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy).

The current 'apt' version of `entr` (v5.1) in Ubuntu Jammy (22.04) is too old
for my needs (e.g. the `-z` flag doesn't work.) so I'm compiling my own from
[the latest v5.3 source release](https://github.com/eradman/entr/releases/tag/5.3).

I know there are a lot of questions about quoting in Bash, but I don't see any that seem to match this. Apologies if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assemble the command as an array, instead of a string.

I read somewhere that maybe `$@` might do what I need, so I put the parts of `$cmd` into an array:

```bash
in="$1"
out="${in%.md}.html"
cmd=(pandoc "$in" -o "$out")
echo "$in" | entr "${cmd[@]}"
```

This correctly quotes the items in `${cmd[@]}` which require it (e.g. have spaces in.)

```bash
+ entr pandoc 'READ ME.md' -o 'READ ME.html'
```

So ‘entr’ successfully calls ‘pandoc’, which successfully converts the documents. It works! I confess I did not expect that.

This approach seems viable for other similar situations, not just when invoking `entr`.

So I have a solution. It doesn't seem completely ideal for my future plans. I had visions of these 'file conversion commands' being configurable, and hence defined in a text file somewhere, so that users (==me, probably) could override them and define their own, and I'm not fluent enough with Bash to be sure how to go about that when commands are defined as arrays instead of strings.

I can't help but feel I've overlooked something simpler.

Comment: This is the answer I would have suggested. It's definitely the right approach. For more details see [BashFAQ/050: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: If you post your "future plans" paragraph as a separate question we can help you figure that part out.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I will take you up on the separate question idea, but now it's bedtime :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a shell to interpret the value of `"$cmd"`, ie:

```bash
# replace this:
echo "$in" | entr "$cmd"
# with this:
echo "$in" | entr sh -c "$cmd"
```

Similarly, `entr` has a `-s` option which invokes a shell for you (chosen using the first word in `$SHELL`):

```bash
echo "$in" | entr -s "$cmd"
```

Using '-s' works equally well, and 'entr' helpfully prints "Bash exit value: x" to stdout each time it executes $cmd, which may or may not be what you want.